# replace complete HTML file content from javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a html file under my war folder in the project ,
I just want to access that file From the path "/myhtml.html"
and then replace whatever is in this file from a new text "Some new Text"

so that My html file now will only have "some new text" there .

I searched alot for this , but they provide example for changing a specific div etc in a file , but i just want to replace everything in a file which is present under a war folder.

Comment: You cannot access local files directly from javascript, try using [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to change the content of HTML files using Javascript that is running in the browser.

Front-end Javascript can't access local files that are stored on your machine. It would be a security disaster if it could. The only way Javascript can read with local files is using a file upload input, and it will only be able to read the files not update/overwrite them.

NodeJS however is capable of accessing the local file system. NodeJs is backend JavaScript so it will be running on a server.

Comment: NodeJs to access local file system must be running on the local system, or if on a server it will only access the server's filesystem. Just my 2c